# multi mechanize transanction errors

Tags: python, linux, performance, performance-testing

i am doing a sample run on a webserver using multi-mechanize and urllib2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib2
import time
import random

class Transaction(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        start_timer = time.time()
        resp = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.16.114/1.html')
        content = resp.read()
        latency = time.time() - start_timer

        self.custom_timers['Example_Homepage'] = latency
        assert (resp.code == 200), 'Bad Response: HTTP %s' % resp.code
        assert ('Example Web Page' in content), 'Text Assertion Failed'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    trans = Transaction()
    trans.run()
    print trans.custom_timers
```

after running the project, i can see errors for each transanctions, but not sure what the errors are as I can see the webserver responding to the requests correctly, can anyone advise?

```
[root@dev1-proxy3 scripts]# multimech-run k1_testrun

  user_groups:  2
  threads: 6

[================100%==================]  30s/30s   transactions: 23879  timers: 23879  errors: 23879



analyzing results...

transactions: 23888
errors: 23888

test start: 2013-01-26 12:59:23
test finish: 2013-01-26 12:59:53

created: ./k1_testrun/results/results_2013.01.26_12.59.23/results.html

done.
```

Comment: you may need to initialize self.custom_timers to {}

Comment: did that but it still gives error

Comment: first run it directly without multi-mech

Comment: Are you sure that the webpage @ http://192.168.16.114/1.html contains the exact text "Example Web Page"?  

Also turning console logging = on in the config.cfg might produce interesting results.

What does the results csv file show?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable verbose logging in config file (by default it's off), then you could find the information you are looking for in log file. It helped in my case.

```
console_logging = on
```